# How to avoid typeid when the type is argument

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, typeid

I'm working on a physics project simulation where I need to calculate the potential of 2 molecules.

and this is part of the code that I thought to write:

```
class Molecule
{
    public:
    double someBulshit;
    virutal double Potential(const Molecule & mol);
}

class LC : public Molecule
{
    public:
    virtual double Potential(const Molecule & mol)
    {
        if(typeid(mol) ==typeid(LC))
            return 1;// for the example
        return 3;
    }

}
class Col : public Molecule
{
    public:
    virtual double Potential(Molecule mol)
    {
        if (typeid(mol) == typeid(Col))
            return 2;
        return 3;
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        Molecule mol1 = new Col();
        Molecule mol2 = new LC();

        double my_potential = mol1.Potential(mol2);
        printf ("%f",my_potential); 
    }
```

I heard that using typeid is bad, but I cant find another way to do so without using it.
This is also performance sensitive and typeid I understood that typeid is not recommended with it.

I tried to split to different functions:

```
double Potential(const LC & mol);
double Potential(const Col & mol);
```

But then I cant call them polymorphic..

Comment: That's not C++ code.

Comment: I converted it from C#
and I need it to work on CPP.
but the point is not the language it's the concept.

Comment: Is there any strong reason that this problem is solved by inheritance? You could assign IDs to the different type of molecules, then create a 2D table of the potentials. This would be as fast as possible.

Comment: @geza I might do that in the end,
but just for the big picture, there are different type of parameters for each type of molecule (colloid/Liquid crystals) so inheritance looked natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of **double dispatch**. The usual recommendation here is the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). However, I don't recommend it in this case.

I think, that you should keep the Molecule base, and the derived classes. You should add an ID into the Molecule class. And implement double dispatch with a 2D table, indexed by the 2 objects' ID. Like this:

```
class Molecule {
  private:
    int m_id;
  public:
    Molecule(int id) : m_id(id) { }

    int id() const {
      return m_id;
    }
};

class LC: public Molecule {
  private:
    // members here
  public:
    LC() : Molecule(0) { }
};

class Col: public Molecule {
  private:
    // members here
  public:
    Col() : Molecule(1) { }
};

double potential_lc_vs_lc(const Molecule &a, const Molecule &b) {
  const LC &lc_a = static_cast<LC &>(a);
  const LC &lc_b = static_cast<LC &>(b);
  // calculate potential LC (lc_a) vs LC (lc_b) here
  return ...;
}

// all the potential_XX_vs_XX functions come here

const double (*potentialCalculatorTable[2][2])(const Molecule &, const Molecule &) = { { potential_lc_vs_lc, potential_lc_vs_col }, ... };

double calculatePotential(const Molecule &a, const Molecule &b) {
  return (*potentialCalculatorTable[a.id()][b.id()])(a, b);
}
```

This needs some manual management, but the solution is clear (in my opinion), and fast.